# PDF "is damaged and can't be opened" on mounted drive

Tags: macos, mount

I have a late 2013 MBP, OSX v10.10. I have a drive mounted via ssh tunnelling. The basic command looks like:

```
alias mountCS='ssh -f useru@host1 -L port:host2 -N ; sshfs -p port user@localhost:remoteDir /Users/User/mnt/CS'
```

While ssh'ed in to the same remote host I created a pdf from latex. When I try open to take a peek from mounted dir I get the error "“results.pdf” is damaged and can’t be opened. You should eject the disk.". However, this happens with R pdfs too. If I simply copy it to a local directory it opens fine though. Odd right? When I first set this sshfs mount up, it didn't do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When this happens to me, I delete the ._results.pdf file, and then I can open it from the mounted directory.

Comment: Yes that's what I've been doing. Just seems like an imperfect solution

Answer (score 1):

This is related to [Files wrongly considered as damaged in encfs volume](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/129966/files-wrongly-considered-as-damaged-in-encfs-volume) and probably this bug: https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/issues/162 - so upgrading to a newer version of sshfs should work, but I've found that it works if you start sshfs with `-o allow_root`, so

`sshfs -o allow_root hostname:path mountpoint`

Hope that helps!